# lost RAID on upgrade from 14 to 16

Tags: upgrade, raid

I had a RAID1 mirrored pair set up in MSI motherboard bios and used for data storage, not for boot. I upgraded(?) from 14.04 to 16.04LTS and lost the RAID pair. The individual disks are seen and the properties show that they are each part of a RAID but I cannot find a way to mount the RAID. My SAMBA was tied to the RAID and it did does not function.

Comment: Was the RAID managed by your hardware? or by the OS. If it was managed by the MSI motherboard BIOS then the fix will likely need to be done on that BIOS (Ubuntu will use whatever it sees; it it now sees two where it used to see one; the BIOS is where it'll have changed I bet)

Comment: When I go to the motherboard setup, it shows that the RAID is set up properly and has a name which referred to in 14.04, but for some reason is not seen by the upgraded version. I set this up several years ago and have lost the original documentation I used.

Comment: I upgraded because of repeated messages that it was time for an upgrade. I expected the existing configuration to be respected. I see in the forum that for ver 16 installations there is an alternate procedure to be used if there is a hardware raid but none of the alternate installs refer to RAID. Is there any possibility that if I upgrade to 18 that this might resolve?

Comment: No i doubt upgrading to Ubuntu Core 18 would fix anything; more often than not, an upgrade with a problem just leaves a more difficult problem to solve. Does your /etc/fstab (file system table) refer to the RAID name as named in your BIOS?  This is where I'd hope to find your resolution.

Comment: The only fstab directory I find is in root, it dies not exist in etc

Comment: The RAIS does not appear in fstab.

Comment: I am not accustomed to using forums - I keep hitting carriage return. The BIOS identifies the RAID as LD2 - AHCI HBA MMIO base FEB51000

Comment: I have no experience using Ubuntu Core releases (*year* only), but were this a normal *year.month* releases I'd believe the lack of a populated /etc/fstab is your problem.  I'd hope `lsblk`, `blkid` & like would recognize your array so you could re-populate your file system table so it mounts on boot or as you require (be it script mounted or whatever you used before)